# Sql value dependent on time

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm building a database of buses in warehouse inventory. The company will buy additional buses over time, these purchases are planned and the rows for these buses have a future purchase date. Some buses currently in inventory have planned seating capacity additions. Is there a way to have a value in the database that's dependent on the date?

For example, if I query for buses in inventory on `2019-03-04`, `Bus13` will have `35` in seating capacity, but if I query for `2020-01-01`, `Bus13` will have `37` in seating capacity.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Some people are voting to close as unclear. I suggest you rewrite a bit for clarity. I assume the business issue is that a bus, like an airplane, can have the seats re-arranged or replaced, thereby resulting in a different capacity. I suggest you explain those details. Ironically, if you made your example more detailed and explicit I suspect you would discover the solution for your database structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a [Type 2 Dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension#Type_2:_add_new_row).  It is basically rows with effective and end dates.  For instance:

```
create table busses (
    bus_id int auto_increment primary key,
    capacity int not null,
    eff_date datetime,
    end_date datetime,
    created_at datetime
);
```

When you insert a new row, you need to "close" the previous row and add a new one.  This is often done in a stored procedure or in application logic.

Comment: I suggest this is a tradeoff between simplicity and redundancy.  `end_date` is redundant with `eff_date` of the next entry; redundancy is a no-no in databases.  On the other hand, it simplifies the code quite a lot.

Comment: The comments above say this is a redundant solution, but it's actually perfect for what I'm looking for with my level of coding knowledge. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [bus]-|---0<[capacity]

The [Answer by Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54524601/642706) is correct, but is for a de-normalized data warehouse.

In a normalized relational database, you would have a `bus` table parent with children in a `capacity` table. The `capacity` would have a start and stop date, whole values do not overlap with sibling rows for the same parent. SQL makes no provision for this, so your app logic or stored procedure must enforce the neatness of the date ranges (abutting, not overlapping, no gaps).

When you want to know the capacity of a bus, you must specify a date, and then do a join across the two tables.

A bus with no capacity rows would mean it is brand-new and not yet deployed to the fleet. Once deployed, a bus would always have at least one row in the `capacity` table.

For the latest record, for the capacity currently in effect, we must decide what to do about the stop date. Some might suggest a `null`, but I agree with [Chris Date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_J._Date) in recommending the avoidance of `null` whenever possible. I would choose a specific date in the future as a placeholder. But not *too* far as some databases or software libraries may be limited.

As Thorsten Kettner commented on this Answer, technically the Stop date column on the `capacity` table is redundant and could be omitted if your date-range abutment code is correct and complete.

Comment: You can do this without a stop date of course, because it is redundant anyway. An entry is always valid until the next start date. Storing the stop date redundantly, however, makes it much easier to select the appropriate row for a date.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Good point, the **Stop date is indeed redundant** and may be omitted if your date-range abutment logic is correct and complete. I don’t trust my own lousy coding to that degree, and have always included a Stop date in this kind of scenario to verify my logic and facilitate debugging.